# IE7 Bug where text gets cut off inside a child div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-7

I have been struggling with this issue for a while. I have a problem with text inside a child div being cut off in IE7 or 8. Works fine in other browsers.

parent div - float left
child div - no height, text gets cut off

I have tried a few hacks and methods I found googling but nothing works, please help!

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample that reproduces the issue?

Comment: What hacks did you try? Did you try overflow:hidden on the parent div and or follow the child div with a clear div with the clear:both style?

Answer (score 3):

Set the `position` style attribute of the parent div to `relative` in your IE style sheet and you should be home free.

Comment: This solution worked when the text was being cut off vertically.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem I found that a combination of clear:both and min-height:[whatever height you need]; worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same type of issue.  My solution was to set a width on the parent div.  Since I wanted it fluid I just set it to 100% and this caused the inner content to show back up.

Hope this helps.